# Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: java

package snippet;
Estoy usando el bucle for para iterar sobre los elementos de una listas y usando getBoolean para pasarle el valor entero pero me salta el error de que es un argumento ilegal.

```java
public class LibroEjercicio16 {

    public static int calcularMCD(int numero1, int numero2) {
        int MCD = 1;
        int[] divisoresNumero1 = calcularDivisores(numero1);
        int[] divisoresNumero2 = calcularDivisores(numero2);
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= calcularCantidadDivisore(numero1); i++) {
            int index = divisoresNumero1[i];
            System.out.println(divisoresNumero1[i]);
            Boolean iterador = java.lang.reflect.Array.getBoolean(divisoresNumero2, index);

            if (iterador) {
                MCD *= i;
            }
        }

        return MCD;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas intentando obtener un `Boolean` de un array de `int`. El método `getBoolean` de `Array` te traera el valor booleano de un array especificado(primer párametro) en una posición dada(segundo parámetro)

Deberías usar el metodo `getInt` para ese tipo de array